# State is not ready when i need it to send it via react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Ok so the problem is in title, i update a state value to use it right after into a React Navigation object who will be send as params to next page.

**here my state declaration :**

```
const [dataForDetailsPage, setDataForDetailsPage] = useState('')
```

**here my onPress :**

```
{results.map((item, i) =>
              <ListItem thumbnail key={i} style={{ marginBottom: 5, marginTop: 5 }}>
                    <Left>
                        {itemPicture !== undefined ?
                            <Thumbnail square large source={{ uri: results[i].media.logo.big }} />
                         : <Thumbnail square large source={{ uri: results[i].media.logo.small }} />
                                              }
                   </Left>
                     <Body>
                        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text note numberOfLines={1}>{item.address}</Text>
                        <Text note numberOfLines={1}>{item.postalcode} {item.city}</Text>
                     </Body>
                     <Right >
                        <Text style={s.voirPlusBtnTxt} onPress={() => { goToDetailPage(item.name) }}>Voir +</Text>
                     </Right>
                    </ListItem>
                                    )}
```

**and here my function called onPress event :(had to found a trick but only works on double click cause first time i click i don't enter in second condition somehow even if i change my state value before)**

```
function goToDetailPage(itemName) {
    
    setDataForDetailsPage(itemName)
    console.log('itemName : '+itemName) //itemName return the value i want
    if(dataForDetailsPage === ''){
        setDataForDetailsPage(itemName)
    }

    if(dataForDetailsPage != ''){
        console.log('DataForDetailsPage : '+ dataForDetailsPage) 
        navigation.navigate('Details', {
            nameFromResultsPage: dataForDetailsPage
        })
    }  
}
```

i tryed to put the function as async function and do a await before setDataForDetailPage but same problem.

Comment: tried to use setState callback? `setDataForDetailsPage(itemName, yourCallbackFunction)`

Comment: @CalvinNunes The `useState` setter does not accept a callback like the class-based `setState`.

Comment: Why not just navigate with the `itemName` value instead of trying to store it in state and waiting a render cycle to navigate?

Comment: @Drew Reese , cause i'm dumb  lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening because the setter function of `useState` (setDataForDetailsPage) is async which meant that the rest of the code doesn't wait to run until it finishes.

You need to setup a `useEffect` to run every time `dataForDetailsPage` is updated.

Like this

```
useEffect(() => {

    if(dataForDetailsPage != ''){
        console.log('DataForDetailsPage : '+ dataForDetailsPage) 
        navigation.navigate('Details', {
            nameFromResultsPage: dataForDetailsPage
        })
    } 
},[dataForDetailsPage])
```

Comment: Thx this works just fine :)